# can't remove border in AdMob google sense ads

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, admob

I receive ads in the following code.
When the ad is Google Sense , I receive a blue border on the ad.
1) I can't change the border type to none (this is what important to me). 
2) Also I can't change the color of the ad in the following code in the UIViewController in the property request.additionalParameters
I set in my application setting at AdMob to use client color

info:
xcode 4.2 for IOS with objective C
ADMob SDK 5.5

code:

```
GADBannerView *banner;
banner =[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height -    GAD_SIZE_320x50.height, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

banner = [[GADBannerView alloc]
          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                   self.view.frame.size.height -
                                   GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                   GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                   GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
banner.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
banner.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:banner];
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.additionalParameters =  [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"FFFF00", @"color_bg",
                                 @"008000", @"color_bg_top",
                                 @"FF00FF", @"color_border",
                                 @"FF0000", @"color_link",
                                 @"808080", @"color_text",
                                 @"00FF00", @"color_url",
                                 nil];
[banner loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it's a backend issue on the AdMob side. Doesn't seem like there's a workaround for this right now until they fix it. This issue is only happening to me for AdSense backfilled ads though.

Comment: That was what I thoghut, But I wasn't sure. Also thanks for your replay at the admob group